# Aggravating Issue with Mouse Event

Tags: java, input, mouse, game-physics

For my computer science class, I was asked to create a game. Everything was going smoothly until I came upon the issue of mouse input. What I am trying to accomplish is to click a mouse at a certain position in the JFrame, then have a bullet initialize at my character's spot and shoot towards the point of the mouse. I already understand how to use trig in order to get the bullet to shoot at that angle. The problem is that when I shoot a bullet after clicking the mouse, the x and y positions of my character are not updated to the bullet, meaning that the bullet always initializes in the same place. Here are code segments in which I believe are causing the problem.

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
{       
    handler.addObject(new Bullet("res\\Fireball.png",x,y + ,ID.BasicEnemy,handler));
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
{
}


public void tick() 
{

    x+=velX;
    y+=velY;

    x = Game.clamp(x,0,Game.WIDTH-40);
    y = Game.clamp(y,0,Game.HEIGHT-40);

    collision();


}
```

From what I gathered through research, the reason why the x and y in mousePressed() method is not updating is because the mouse event is in a different thread than my tick. I'm a little new to java game programming and I was wondering if there would be anyone out there who could give me explicit suggestions. The actual code of my game is very long, so I narrowed it down to the piece of code above.(I tried synchronized reserved word and volatile variables, but I might have implemented them wrong)

And if this helps, conversely, if I do this below, the bullet object never appears!

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
{       
    press=true;
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
{
    press=false;
}


public void tick() 
{

    x+=velX;
    y+=velY;

    x = Game.clamp(x,0,Game.WIDTH-40);
    y = Game.clamp(y,0,Game.HEIGHT-40);


    collision();

    if (press)
        handler.addObject(new Bullet("res\\Fireball.png",(int)x,(int)y ,ID.BasicEnemy,handler));
}
```

Comment: regarding `"Aggravating Issue with Mouse Event"` your question title should be a summary of your actual code problem, not a rant or kvetch.

Comment: One possible issue, you never use the MouseEvent object, `e` in your `mousePressed(MouseEvent e)` method body. This object holds the location of the click, and I don't think that you want to ignore it.

Comment: You're creating two bullets, it's possible that the `tick` isn't (always) seeing the `press` state depending on how your `tick` is been called

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {       
    handler.addObject(new Bullet("res\\Fireball.png",x,y + ,ID.BasicEnemy,handler));
}
```

You never use the MouseEvent Point object, but seem to use an unchanging x and y value. Perhaps (hard to say) you want to use the x and y from the MouseEvent object:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {       
    handler.addObject(new Bullet("res\\Fireball.png", e.getX(), e.getY(), 
        ID.BasicEnemy, handler));
}
```

If this does not solve your problem, then consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Ah, close enough :P (I'm confused, but I've had no sleep - so not much different)